# Node JS MySQL Insert Query of Multiple Variables ER_PARSE_ERROR

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, string, server

I have created a webhook to receive some data here using Node.JS. I am storing my data using MySQL and so far the server is able to connect to the database, receive client data, and respond appropriately upon receiving data. I am just having issues formatting the query string for MySQL.

I have tried a variety of quotation configurations such as not wrapping the column names in single quotes, not wrapping the table name, and switching between double and single quotes on each section in the query string.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you!

My Query:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO 'cms'('ts', 'orgid', 'orgname', 'deviceid', 'devicename', 'event', 'setid', 'setname', 'viewid', 'viewname', 'duration', 'hotspotid', 'hotspotname', 'playlistid', 'playlistname', 'playlisttype', 'playlistassetid', 'playlisttitle') VALUES ("+timestamp+", "+orgid+", "+orgname+", "+deviceid+", "+devicename+", "+eventname+", "+setid+", "+setname+", "+viewid+", "+viewname+", "+duration+", "+hotspotid+", "+hotspotname+", "+playlistid+", "+playlistname+", "+playlisttype+", "+playlistassetid+", "+playlisttitle+")";
                            con.query(sql, function (err, result) { //Queries String with MySQL connection variable con
                                    if (err) throw err;
                                    var date = new Date();
                                    var currHour = date.getHours();
                                    console.log("Record Inserted at " + currHour); //Logs time of db insertion on console
                            });
```

Here is the error too:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''cms'('ts', 'orgid', 'orgname', 'deviceid', 'devicename', 'event', 'setid', 'set' at line 1
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/webhook/httpHandler/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/webhook/httpHandler/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:77:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/webhook/httpHandler/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:278:23)
at Parser.write (/home/webhook/httpHandler/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
at Protocol.write (/home/webhook/httpHandler/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/webhook/httpHandler/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/webhook/httpHandler/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/home/webhook/httpHandler/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
at Connection.query (/home/webhook/httpHandler/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:200:25)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/webhook/httpHandler/server.js:70:9)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

Comment: Could you please show the exact result of your formatting code? What is the resulting sql?

Comment: There is no resulting SQL because the node js script never executes, but I may be misunderstanding your question. Do you just want to see the rest of the script?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is around this code:

```
VALUES ("+timestamp.toString()+"
```

Could you try to escape those double quoute characters?

Comment: Not sure how the ".toString()" made it into this post, I removed that already and still receiving the same error. My apologies on that

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to make a stored procedure that takes parameters instead of opening yourself up to SQL Injection.

My second suggestion is normalize your tables. If you're adding both ID and Name for more than the table's key data, it's a bad design.

Other than that, Roi is right. You need to wrap several of your values in escaped quotes:

var sql = "INSERT INTO cms (`ts`, `orgid`, `orgname`, `deviceid`, `devicename`, `event`, `setid`, `setname`, `viewid`, `viewname`, `duration`, `hotspotid`, `hotspotname`, `playlistid`, `playlistname`, `playlisttype`, `playlistassetid`, `playlisttitle`) VALUES ('"+timestamp.toString()+"', "+orgid+", '"+orgname+"', "+deviceid+", '"+devicename+"', '"+eventname+"', "+setid+", '"+setname+"', "+viewid+", '"+viewname+"', "+duration+", "+hotspotid+", '"+hotspotname+"', "+playlistid+", '"+playlistname+"', '"+playlisttype+"', "+playlistassetid+", '"+playlisttitle+"')"

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this instead.

```
var sql = `INSERT INTO 'cms'('ts', 'orgid', 'orgname', 'deviceid', 'devicename', 'event', 'setid', 'setname', 'viewid', 'viewname', 'duration', 'hotspotid', 'hotspotname', 'playlistid', 'playlistname', 'playlisttype', 'playlistassetid', 'playlisttitle') VALUES ("${timestamp}", "${orgid}" ...)`;
```